# More control of serial?

Tags: serial

I am trying to control some really old proprietary hardware. I hooked a scope up and could determine that I need to send it essentially 21 bits in a row. It is a clock. so the fist seven are hours, second seven are minutes, and last seven are seconds. They need to be all "smashed" together as one big hunk of 21 bits, no stop bit etc.

So my question is how to do this? I have played around with wiringSerial library and a few others but cannot just send raw bits like I need. Any ideas out there? Thanks for taking up the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) will let you generate any waveform you want.  From the command line (pigs) or C or Python.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you won't find anything which will do this.

It is not that hard to do. In the good old days when UARTs were expensive technology we used to do serial by bit-banging. Thee Pi could certainly do the same. It depends on how fast, how often data needs to be sent and how precise the timing needs to be.

If only one-off or infrequent transmission is needed assemble the data (including any start bit or synch pattern) in an integer and shift out to a GPIO pin using a delay. You could use a timer interrupt for faster speeds.

You could also use SPI to shift the data out for more demanding applications.